# How do you get ANativeWindow from a SurfaceTexture in the NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've got some OpenGL ES code that has been rendering to a `GLSurfaceView`, and I'm currently modifying it to work with either `SurfaceView` and `TextureView`.

The common element I need from both inside my native code is: `ANativeWindow`.

For the `SurfaceView` I got it by passing `Surface` to:

```
m_jwindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
```

For `TextureView`, I take `SurfaceTexture`, and in API 14 I can use this:

```
m_jwindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture(env, surface);
```

However, that function was removed in Jellybean. Which leaves me wondering, how can I get `ANativeWindow` from a `SurfaceTexture` in API 16+?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do in API 16+ is create a Surface object, passing the SurfaceTexture as an argument to the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#Surface%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) (which was introduced in API 14).  Pass that Surface to `ANativeWindow_fromSurface()` as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is there anyone can see this.

first, include `surface_texture.h`

use `ASurfaceTexture_fromSurfaceTexture(JNIEnv *env, jobject surfacetexture)` to get `ASurfaceTexture*`

then use `ASurfaceTexture_acquireANativeWindow(ASurfaceTexture *st)` to get `ANativeWindow*`

make sure release it after everything done. `ASurfaceTexture_release(ASurfaceTexture *st)`

reference: https://developer.android.google.cn/ndk/reference/group/surface-texture

Comment: Very handy to have a more recent answer.