# How to create ANativeWindow using NDK?

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I want to analyse video in background(no UI) using NDK and opengl. I would like to decode the video and render in on a texture(memory). How we can do it?

I tried using AMediaCodec to directly render on a texture. But problem is it needs ANativeWindow(in AMediaCodec_configure) which I'm not able to create from opengl texture(created using glGenTextures). Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312632/how-do-you-get-anativewindow-from-a-surfacetexture-in-the-ndk/

Comment: hi fadden..thanks for the response. This particular example creates ANativeWindow from java surface object which I dont have. I was looking for something like ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture which is no longer available :(

Comment: Looks like this is NOT possible. I ended up building Android source code, using stagefright along with ffmpeg. It gives me to select h/w decoder and performance is really good.
Suggestion: In case you dont need to display video and want to process use stagefright along with ffmpeg. It will take couple of days to build and use it.

Comment: Hi @raknas, how did you build the Android source code with stagefright and ffmpeg? Can you maybe point me to a resource that you used or describe the required steps. I have also connected my linkedin to Stackoverflow so you could also message me there :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did it long time back.

Here are the steps:
1. Build android - https://source.android.com/setup/building
1.1. Take the stagefrieght APIs and so, and put it under your source tree.
1.2 Take OMXclient if you want to use the decoder components.
2. Build ffmpeg  - http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/
2.2 Take the required ffmpeg component - I used it primarily to demux mov files

Using stagefright you should able to create