# How to pass a surface in Android to native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'd like to work with the Native Window, so I'm trying to call ANativeWindow_fromSurface, but it needs a jobject for the surface. I'm assuming the best way to do this would be to pass this in when onSurfaceCreated is called, i.e.:

```
public class RendererWrapper implements Renderer {
     @Override
     public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
     // (Some sort of code that would create a surface object)

     //This is a native function that will use ANativeWindow_fromSurface
     cOnSurfaceCreated(surface);
}
```

But I don't know what specific object I should be using nor how to access it.

Edit: I'm trying to do something like the NativeWindow API in this example: https://vec.io/posts/how-to-render-image-buffer-in-android-ndk-native-code so I can write directly to the screen from native c code,.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you need to be passing it a Surface.  I would expect your `onSurfaceCreated()` method to be called *after* the Surface was created, so I'm not quite understanding the structure of the code you're showing.

If you're working with a SurfaceTexture, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312632/how-do-you-get-anativewindow-from-a-surfacetexture-in-the-ndk/).

Comment: How would I access a Surface that corresponds to the device's screen? Is that what Surfaces even do? I looked around and found that I can get a surface _view_ by calling `SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context)` (where I can access the context just fine). But when I looked for how to do that with a Surface, it needs a SurfaceTexture, which in turn needs a texName, and I can't figure out what either of those are or how I would use/access them.

Comment: For the full details, see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html . For examples, see Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika). There is no such thing as The Device Screen (except perhaps in "recovery" mode). Surfaces have a producer end and a consumer end; for a SurfaceView, the app is the producer, and the system graphics compositor is the consumer. You draw on the Surface, and SurfaceFlinger gets it onto the display. On a rooted device you can shut the entire app framework down and access HardwareComposer directly, but that's rarely useful.