# Android NDK Output MediaCodec to a GL Texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

In Android Java side, following code can be used to output the `mediacodec` to a GL texture.

```
int [] hTex = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, hTex, 0);
SurfaceTexture mSTexture = new SurfaceTexture(hTex[0]);
Surface s = new Surface(mSTexture);
mPlayer = new PlayerThread(s);
```

But how to do that in NDK?

I can use`glGenTextures` to create a GL texture, but the param type of `AMediaCodec_configure` is `ANativeWindow*`, is there a way to convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312632/how-do-you-get-anativewindow-from-a-surfacetexture-in-the-ndk .

Comment: hi fadden, thanks, but not duplicate, want to do all of these in NDK.

you know, the param type of AMediaCodec_configure is ANativeWindow*, in NDK,  is there a way to convert GLtexture created by native glGenTextures to ANativeWindow*?

Comment: Sure... render the texture onto the Surface. The example in your question is converting video frames (sent to a Surface) to a texture, not texture to Surface.

Comment: :( seems i explained not clearly.

First i created a texture by native glGenTextures, then how to generate a surface in NDK by this textureID, so that this surface can be used as output surface of mediacodec.

after mediacodec updated the surface, i will use the textureID to do other things.

Comment: @fadden, is this possible in NDK?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to call `new SurfaceTexture()` via JNI - there's no equivalent to that on the NDK level. The problem is that you need to implement a java observer/callback interface as well, so doing this via JNI is pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The project I am recently working on also has to get the ANativeWindow* from a gl texture. Here is how I did it with JNI:

First, get a surfacetexture 'jobject' from your gl texture

```
jclass surfacetexture_class = Env->FindClass("android/graphics/SurfaceTexture");
jmethodID surfacetexture_init = Env->GetMethodID(surfacetexture_class, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject surfacetexture_obj = Env->NewObject(surfacetexture_class, surfacetexture_init, (jint)your_gl_texture);
```

Then, convert the jobject surfacetexture to native ASurfaceTexture* using `ASurfaceTexture_fromSurfaceTexture(Env, surfacetexture_obj)`

Finally, `ASurfaceTexture_acquireANativeWindow(surfacetexture)` gives you the ANativeWindow* associated with your gl texture