# cannot locate symbol "ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture" referenced by

Tags: android, android-ndk

Execute the application exception occurs

cannot locate symbol "ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture" referenced by

```
System.loadLibrary("aaa");
```

In the aaa.so file used ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture function (Error)

but use ANativeWindow_fromSurface funtion (no problem)

I found Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\android\native_window_jni.h

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 13
/**
 * Return the ANativeWindow associated with a Java SurfaceTexture object,
 * for interacting with it through native code.  This acquires a reference
 * on the ANativeWindow that is returned; be sure to use ANativeWindow_release()
 * when done with it so that it doesn't leak.
 */
ANativeWindow* ANativeWindow_fromSurfaceTexture(JNIEnv* env, jobject surfaceTexture);
#endif
```

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.com.trytryNdk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk{
            ldLibs "log", "z", "m", "OpenMAXAL", "android"
        }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-16"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Which device is this?

Comment: Test device : Sony Z , HUAWEI , Nexus 7 , Nexus 9
Version :　Android 4.4, 5.1 , 7

Comment: I believe that @fadden answered this some while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24313036/192373

Comment: Ugh. APIs aren't supposed to ever be removed like this. I've just uploaded changes to remove the decl and the symbol from the NDK so it will be a build failure rather than a runtime failure.

Answer (score 0):

first, include surface_texture.h

use `ASurfaceTexture_fromSurfaceTexture(JNIEnv *env, jobject surfacetexture)` to get `ASurfaceTexture*`

then use `ASurfaceTexture_acquireANativeWindow(ASurfaceTexture *st)` to get `ANativeWindow*`

make sure release it after everything done. `ASurfaceTexture_release(ASurfaceTexture *st)`

reference: https://developer.android.google.cn/ndk/reference/group/surface-texture

Comment: This is introduced in api level 28. Not available in lower api levels.

Comment: @UdaraWanasinghe really? sorry I am not aware of.